# Reduce compile time for function template by moving implementation and explicit instantiation into source file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compile-time, function-templates

I implemented a function template which uses boost internally and doubles the compile time for a large project. I would like to move the template and all required explicit instantiations from the header into the source file. In the header only a declaration of the template remains. This compiles and reduces compile times as expected, but my dll cannot be linked, because the symbols are missing from the object file (`dumpbin /symbols` does not list them).
Also I want to use the template in other dlls.
And the solution has to work on MSVC and GCC.

Comment: If you can't make it work, consider instead letting the function template delegate to a single ordinary non-type-safe function in the DLL.

Comment: Templates are a compile time code generation mechanism. You'll have to instantiate your template with all possible combinations of parameters and link that to your DLL. Or, of course, have the template code header only. The third option is to extract the part of the template code, that is independent from the template parameters, implement that in a common base class and have the rest in the header. That not only reduces the compile time, but the code size as well.

Comment: @cdonat: the instantiation for all possible parameters and linking is exactly what I am trying to achieve, but I cannot get it to link, because the explicit instantiation creates no symbols in the object file

Comment: @mgr Ah, you'll have to instantiate all the methods as well. When a Template class is instantiated and used, the compiler creates only that code, that it knows, will be used.

Comment: @cdonat: No, it is not a class template. It is a function template which I want to instantiate and use for about 15 different types.

Comment: @mgr then I guess, you assumptions about the types you actually use are incorrect. The compiler of the using code tries to compile e.g. with `T` and you have `const T&`, or something like that.

Comment: @cdonat: the types are certainly correct. They are e.g. int and unsigned and the linker error tells me, that it is looking for int and unsigned versions of the function template. But if there are no symbols generated in the object file for any instantiation at all, the linker has to fail.

Comment: @mgr Hm, are you sure, you have the template instantiation correct? Do you correctly link the object file with the instantiations to the library? Are the symbols correctly exported?

Comment: @cdonat: the explicit instantiation should be correct, because I got it wrong first and the compiler warning told me about that. The object file is linked, because other non-template functions in it are linked correctly. How do I export the symbols correctly? What needs to be done in the header, what in the source file? I tried several combinations of export, __declspec(dllexport), extern, etc.